# tensorflow slice dimension,change only a channel of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to multiply a channel by 2. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work, anybody knows why?

```
preds = tf.add_n(bases, name="output")
output_list = []
for i in range(3):
    if i == 0:
        output_list.append(tf.multiply(preds[:,:,:,i],2))
    output_list.append(preds[:,:,:,i])
preds = tf.stack(output_list)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. what is the output that you get? Or is it an error? Please show it in your question for others to better help you!

Comment: One possible bug in your code is that there's no `else` clause, so the first layer will be added twice